# Is Accuracy differentiable for neural network models?

Tags: functions, derivatives, optimization, neural-networks

I saw many classifiers aim to obtain a high accuracy in deep learning. And people use different kinds of loss functions, like cross-entropy, L1, or L2 loss.

The accuracy is defined as $$ Accuracy = \frac{TP + TN}{TP + TN + FP + FN}$$

Is it possible to directly maximize the accuracy as loss function?  Can we solve $$ max_\theta \qquad \text{Accuracy}(y, y')$$ directly? Here $y$ is the true label and $y'$ is the predicted value.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Two issues here. Unless you have a balanced dataset, maximising accuracy is pointless. For example, if your dataset consists of 99% negative examples and 1% positive examples, it is very easy to hit high accuracy simply by classifying all examples as negative.

Secondly, I don't think your accuracy function is differentiable. Depending on how your neural network decides it's output value, say for instance it outputs a probability then the output $y$ classification for your training input $x$ and let $\theta(x)$ be out put from your neural net is actually a piecewise function:

$$y(\theta(x))\begin{cases} 
1 &\text{if } \theta(x) \geq 0.5\\
0 &\text{otherwise}.
\end{cases}$$

In other words, if one were to differentiate the function $y$ we get zero and any back propagation would be zero.

Comment: It's probably worth mentioning that even if you did somehow modify the way accuracy is calculated so that it *was* differentiable, you essentially have just made another loss function anyway.

Comment: For a binary problem where outputs are either 1 or 0, isn't accuracy same as 1 - MSE (mean absoloute error)? As far as I know MSE is a smooth function. So, can we conclude that accuracy is a smooth function for binary problems?

Comment: Accuracy *is* differentiable in the classic sense used in mathematics. But I believe your usage of "differentiable" is correct in the broader sense that the derivative is not useful.

This distinction is important because, in deep learning, we also use the ReLU function which is also piecewise differentiable.  But its derivative IS useful!  So I think it is helpful here to clarify that "differentiable" means "having a useful derivative" in the context of deep learning.

Comment: To your first point, you are totally right and it is worth mentioning that considering the true positive and false positive rates independently, as in a ROC or precision-recall curve is important here. But the true positive rate and false positive rate are also not differentiable in the useful sense of the word.

Comment: @m.taheri  MSE is also not differentiable as it too compares a discrete rather than continuous derivative when considering a binary classifier. MSE is continuous for a regressor, but we don't use accuracies there.